# How to create a Test Suite in Eclipse under org.junit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

`org.junit.Assert.` has deprecated `junit.framework.Assert`

My question is how do I create a Test Suite in Eclipse if my JUnit classes do not extend a `TestCase`?

When I try to create new Test Suite in Eclipse my classes do not appear in the select box and I imagine this is because they don't extend a `TestCase`.

I thought that with the new `org.junit` I can just use annotation and not extend `TestCase`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code will create a test suite with Junit4.  You can then just run this in Eclipse as a Junit test case.  Obviously the TestClasses need to contain methods annotated with @Test otherwise no tests will actually run for the suite.

```
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class})
public class TestSuite {
  //nothing
}
```

Comment: What is the `TestClass1.class`?

Comment: TestClass1.class and TestClass2.class are the classes which contain your test methods (i.e classes containing methods annotated with @Test).

Answer (score 2):

JUnit 4, which is bundled with eclipse doesn't use the old way of testing, where your testcases and testsuites used to extend classes.

JUnit 4 relies on annotations.

Just right click your project, select "new->other" go to "Test case", select JUnit 4, select the class under test, the methods under test and you've got your test case.
For a test suite, right click the project, select "other", go to "test suite", and select the test case you created in the previous step... or more test cases.